# Conditional routing with promises doesn't work

Tags: angularjs

Good day! Im trying to check user_id cookie on every page and if there is no cookie, redirect to login page. But something goes wrong and application falls because of recursion.
Why this code doesn't work? 
in app.js I have

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: 'partials/login.html', controller: 'loginCtrl'});
  $routeProvider.when('/signup', {templateUrl: 'partials/signup.html', controller: 'signupCtrl', resolve: {factory: checkRouting}});
  $routeProvider.when('/index', {templateUrl: 'index.html', controller: 'MainCtrl', resolve: {factory: checkRouting}});
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);

var checkRouting = function ($q, $rootScope, $http, $location, localStorageService) {
    function redirect(path) {
        if ($location.path() != path) {
            $location.path(path); 
            return $q.reject();
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return getUserDataPromise($q, $rootScope, $http, localStorageService)
        .then(function (result) {
                return redirect("/index");
        }, function (reason) {
            console.error(reason);
            return redirect("/");
        });
};

var getUserDataPromise = function ($q, $rootScope, $http, localStorageService) {
    if ($rootScope.session_id) {
        return $q.when($rootScope.session_id); 
    } else {
        var session_id = localStorageService.cookie.get("session_id");
        if (!session_id) {
            return $q.reject("No session id.");
        } else {
            $rootScope.session_id = session_id;
            return $q.when(session_id);
//             return $q.reject("Error requesting server: " + reason);
        }
    }
```

controllers.js is

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', '$route', '$location', '$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $window, $route, $location, $routeParams) {
      console.log("fffffffff");
  }])
  .controller('loginCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$http', '$window', '$route', '$location', '$routeParams', 'localStorageService', function($rootScope, $scope, $http, $window, $route, $location, $routeParams, localStorageService) {
    $scope.username = "";
    $scope.password = "";
    $scope.auth = false;
    $rootScope.session_id="";
    var sess="mlvdfmvlkcmlkvnxclkjmnvkl561vfd" //for debug
    $scope.submit = function() {
        $scope.secret = "M"
        var responsePromise = $http.post("ajax", { method: "login", login: $scope.username, password: $scope.password, secret: $scope.secret });
        responsePromise.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            if (data.status == "done") {
                $scope.auth = true;
                console.log(data.status);
                localStorageService.cookie.set("session_id", sess);
                $location.path( "/index" );
            };
        });
        responsePromise.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("AJAX failed!");
        });
      };
  }])
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can post a half of your site here and ask why it does'nt work. please can you make a jsFiddle or something ?

Answer (score 0):

Use routeChageStart event, and intercept route change if user doesn't have a session.

For example:

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
    // if route requires auth and user is not logged in
    if (userIsLoggedIn()==false) {
      // redirect back to login
      $location.path('/login');
    }
  });
```

This way any app url would redirec to login if user is not authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks alot for answer.
I understand where I had a trouble. I shouldn't redirect to "/index" page. When I created "partials/main" page and updated code to be redirected to "/main", recursion has gone.